# 'git log -<number> --pretty="format:%H"' output does NOT append newline when piped into 'cat -e'

Tags: bash, shell, git-log

I'm creating a shell script that displays the commit IDs of the 5 last git commits of my git repository.

Name of the script file: 'git_commit.sh'
By "commit ID", I mean the full 40-character hexadecimal string.
By git repository, I mean the current branch.

The output I expect:

```
yossi@hostname$ bash git_commit.sh | cat -e
42dfd4bdba4646b28136c4b0d71f76ae352aac10$
63a7f8e9e7f5ab2f29c4227440d78fc731201b89$
57361b98c8cb9041759461093ed38b7b8930e12e$
a05251da02f6c677f38f3ab68c95b2dd8812a822$
d17402aa3e3835e1b9e444482cda233e97e032d6$
yossi@hostname$
```

The command that was inserted in 'git_commit.sh':

```
git log -5 --pretty="format:%H"
```

And here's the output I get when I run the script:

```
yossi@hostname$ bash git_commit.sh | cat -e
42dfd4bdba4646b28136c4b0d71f76ae352aac10$
63a7f8e9e7f5ab2f29c4227440d78fc731201b89$
57361b98c8cb9041759461093ed38b7b8930e12e$
a05251da02f6c677f38f3ab68c95b2dd8812a822$
d17402aa3e3835e1b9e444482cda233e97e032d6yossi@hostname$
```

PROBLEM

- The 5th and last commit ID is not followed by a trailing $.
- There's no line break before the next command prompt.

Which means that there was no newline after the 5th and last commit ID when it was piped into the 'cat -e' command.

I thoroughly reviewed the manual page of 'git log' and wasn't able to find anything that explains that behavior.

ALTERNATIVES THAT I TESTED
I tested the replacement of `git log -5 --pretty="format:%H"` by the following three commands:

- `git log -5 --format="%H" | cat -e`
- `git log -5 --pretty="tformat:%H" | cat -e`
- `git log -5 --pretty="%H" | cat -e`

Each of those three alternative commands inserted in 'git_commit.sh' provide the expected output:

```
yossi@hostname$ bash git_commit.sh | cat -e
42dfd4bdba4646b28136c4b0d71f76ae352aac10$
63a7f8e9e7f5ab2f29c4227440d78fc731201b89$
57361b98c8cb9041759461093ed38b7b8930e12e$
a05251da02f6c677f38f3ab68c95b2dd8812a822$
d17402aa3e3835e1b9e444482cda233e97e032d6$
yossi@hostname$
```

Is someone able to explain the difference in behavior of `git log -5 --pretty="format:%H"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation lies here:

> • `tformat`:
> The `tformat:` format works exactly like `format:`, except that it provides "terminator" semantics instead of "separator" semantics. In other words, each commit has the message terminator character (usually a newline) appended, rather than a separator placed between entries. This means that the final entry of a single-line format will be properly terminated with a new line, just as the "oneline" format does. For example:
>
> https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Note that both `git log --format="%H"` and `git log --pretty="%H"` are equivalent to `--pretty="tformat:%H"`:

> `--pretty[=<format>]`
> `--format=<format>`
> Pretty-print the contents of the commit logs in a given format, where `<format>` can be one of `oneline`, `short`, `medium`, `full`, `fuller`, `reference`, `email`, `raw`, `format:<string>` and `tformat:<string>`. When `<format>` is none of the above, and has `%placeholder` in it, it acts as if `--pretty=tformat:<format>` were given.
>
> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---prettyltformatgt

Comment: Strangely, I have a final newline for `git log -5 --pretty="format:%H"`, but not `git log -5 --pretty="format:%H" | cat -e`.

Comment: I would guess that `git log` as a porcelain command always adds a final newline if the output is a tty. So only by piping it to another command or a file you can see its raw output.